# Cross origin error trying to comunicate angular 6 with AWS API gateway

Tags: angular, cors, angular6, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make an angular 6 application communicate with some lambda functions behind aws API gateway.

The thing here is that I allow every origin and the methods supported. And I did really quick a react app, that calls the endpoint and it brings the proper response.

So I really think that the issue is on how I'm doing the call from angular.
here's the service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpHandlerService {
  private SUBMIT_MESSAGE_END_POINT = 'AnActualURL';    

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  public submitAMessage(username, title, message){
    return this.http.post(this.SUBMIT_MESSAGE_END_POINT,{
      "username": username,
      "title": title,
      "message": message
    });
  }
}
```

I did try to add some options parameters, with no luck.

please provide some feedback

I'm very frustrated because I can make the call from everywhere but angular 6.

Comment: What error is the browser reporting in the devtools console?

Comment: Failed to load https://theidofmyapi.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/dev/message: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.    

and if go to network, on response i can see this:
{"message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:********6468:7m4zcfotzd/dev/OPTIONS/message2"}

Comment: That would seem to indicate the `https://theidofmyapi.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/dev/message` endpoint isn’t configure to respond to (unauthenticated) OPTIONS requests. Right now I guess it’s probably responding with a 401, if it’s wrongly requiring authentication for OPTIONS requests). It needs to be configured to respond to unauthenticated OPTIONS request with 200 OK response and with the correct CORS response headers.

Comment: As far as the authentication goes, browser don’t send the the Authorization header nor cookies in the CORS preflight OPTIONS request. That’s why the server must allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have currently a 403 as a response. And I have the auth configured as none required. I think that should make it answer to anonymous or im wrong there? 
im really confuse because if I call it from a react or node with `fetch` i can actually receive a 200 response, and I'm wondering if angular 6 add a header or something. Or what's different between the way angular 6 call it. and fetch way. I cant understand where's the difference